# Terminating each() block in Protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

I was automating the an application (using Protractor) and I have come across situation where I wanted to select the an option from the type ahead using the DOWN arrow button from the Keyboard. Here is how I am approaching to this action.

1. After typing part into the text field I am getting the reference of each option that appear in the type ahead.
2. Now, I am using .each() method of protractor to iterate through each of the option to look for the required option.
3. I'm making the script to hit DOWN arrow button to iterate through each option in the type ahead. 
   Suppose there are 10 options displayed in the type ahead and the option that I need to select is at 5th position. Now when I reach the 5th position I am selecting the option but each() function still continues.

I want the loop to terminate when required option is selected. Something like BREAK statement in FOR loops.

BTW I have tried the above scenario with FOR loop but unable to use BREAK statement within then() handler.

Please let me know how to cope up with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception to terminate the loop. Put the loop inside try and use catch to wrangle your results. You can also just use a boolean variable to indicate that you have found a match and ignore everything after that point. I would just use a for loop though.

Edit:
You could add a variable to hold an action before the allBenchmarks.each

```
var action
```

Then inside the test

```
if(dataValue == optionToSelect){ 
    action = function() {benchmark.click(); ...}
}
```

After the loop exits call the action

```
if (action) action()
```

Comment: The problem is I am unable to access the variable values set inside the **then** handler outside the block. In addition, after making the selection from type ahead it disappears and as loop continues it fails to find the next element reference and throws an error saying "Element not found with so and so XPATH...".

Comment: you need to declare the variable outside (and before) the block if you want it set inside the block and used after. Can you post some code which is not working but shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: here is the code snippet.  allBenchmarks.each(function(benchmark){
                    benchmark.getAttribute("class").then(function(classValue){
                        if(classValue.indexOf("active") > 0){
                            benchmark.getAttribute("data-value").then(function(dataValue){
                                if(dataValue == optionToSelect){
                                    benchmark.click();
                                    defer.fulfill(true);
                                    return promise;
                                }
});
}
});
});

Comment: sorry for the improperly indented code. I am new to the stackoverflow. Thus I don't know how the formatting works.

Comment: I added your code snippet to your original question for you. Also updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for looking into the issue. I appreciate your effort. I have found the workaround where I am using recursive function call to achieve the functionality. One thing I have learned from this is, we can use Recursion as an alternative to each(), for() where breaking the loops is almost impossible in protractor.